# How do i create a simple tree with rpart?

Tags: r, machine-learning, tree, rpart

I'm trying to create a decisiontree in R with rpart.

```
#rm(list = ls())
cat("\014")  

library("rpart")
#data
mf <- factor(c("m","m","f","f","m","f","m"))
heights <-  c(180, 175 , 160, 166, 185, 170, 190)
x = data.frame(cbind(heights, mf))
#create tree
fit <- rpart(mf ~ ., data = x, method = "anova")

predicted <- predict(fit,character = 180)
```

I expect "predicted" to give me an "m" or an "f" but all i get is a trivial number.
What do i need to change to get a letter?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your example is too small, which I addressed by making 3 times as large. Also the "anova" method is designed to predict means of categories. (You also need to throw away the book that taught you to use data.frame(cbind(...))) I'm guessing you want something like this.

```
mf <- factor(c("m","m","f","f","m","f","m"))
heights <-  c(180, 175 , 160, 166, 185, 170, 190)
x = data.frame( heights=rep(heights,3), mf)
rm(heights);rm(mf)
fit <- rpart(mf ~ heights, data = x, method="class")

(predicted <- predict(fit, data.frame(heights = c(160,190) ) ) )
  f m
1 1 0
2 0 1

png(); plot(fit)
par(xpd=NA)
text(fit, use.n = TRUE);dev.off()
```

[image]